# How to get and print mobile node's position in aodv NS3?

Tags: ns-3

I am working with `AODV` in `NS3`. I actually want to print node's position on `routingProtocol.cc`.

Comment: Hi. Can you provide some example of what you have tried in order to help us guide you ?

Answer (score 2):

You can first get the mobility model object from the node. Using the mobility model object, you can then get the coordinates of the node.

```
Ptr<MobilityModel> mob = node->GetObject<MobilityModel>();
double x = mob->GetPosition().x;
double y = mob->GetPosition().y;
double z = mob->GetPosition().z;
```